# Acumatica DAC Extension won't pull data

Tags: acumatica

Having a very frustrating time with a DAC extension.  I've created a series of UDFs for CustSalesPeople, they show up on the page, and I can fill them with data.  When I went to access them programmatically I get a slate of zeros instead of their values.  In the code below it successfully sets usrCommissionTotal to the amount of row.commisionPct.  All other values come through as zero.  What am I missing?[image]

Comment: Profiled the SQL, and the UDF values are definitely coming out of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UsrCommisson1 field is of decimal type. Acumatica requires all DAC fields to be of a nullable type. Will changing type for the UsrCommisson1 field from decimal to decimal? (Nullable) resolve the issue?