# DAC Issue on version 5.30.1465

Tags: object, acumatica, dac

When I create a DAC for using that object on the code, worked on the version 4.20.2344

```
invoice.(somethig)
```

But when I try to call the same object on version 5.3, it does not appear in visual Studio and I can't compile it, could you help me with this issue? Some one has the same problem?

I leave some images for explaining what happened

[Here is the example on v4.20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOncu.png)

[Here is the error example  in the v5.3 can't use the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsjx7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must create a cache extension object for the DAC udfs and then create an instance of it in your code.  See the code attached to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045439/acumatica-dac-extension-wont-pull-data).   NOTE, the code has a slight bug in it, make sure you read the answer!

Comment: i added fields on the tables >
Address
BAccount
ARRegister

but i need to validate the camps with this info on ARInvoiceEntry
how can i get that fields from the tables(address,BAccount).
i need to Instance all ? or exist another way to do this?

Comment: you can create views in ARinvoiceEntry for each element and link them to the Current baccountid or addressid from the Invoice and then create Extension objects from each and pull data out of them.